# What are some resources from which I can obtain difficult math problems?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I study IBDP 1 , and I need math problems which are hard to solve. This is for two reasons:

- They really help in preparing for examinations.
- Solving difficult    problems really fills my heart with joy and
  satisfaction :)

Sometimes, I do find great questions on this awesome website. But, I usually run into questions which are above my knowledge level. So, if any of you could provide links to **challenging math resources**, I will be very thankful.

Comment: What is IBDP1 ? Be aware that something that is called XYZ999 in some part of the world and will be known under this acronym can be completely unknown (which is the case here for your acronym) in the rest of the world. Help us to help you...

Comment: Care to elaborate on your knowledge and background, what maths do you know/care to learn?

Comment: @JeanMarie sorry for the confusion. By IBDP 1, I meant 11th grade in the International Baccalaureate curriculum.

Comment: @ZacharyHunter For now, I would like to focus on Algebra and Calculus.

Comment: Take a look at Olympiads ; be conscious that it needs some preparation ; begin by selecting "english" in the popup menus of https://www.imo-official.org/problems.aspx?&column=year&order=desc&language=en ; begin by 2018, then go backwards : 2017, 2016... You will surely find appealing problems. Begin by the most appealing problems. Solutions can be found elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view) can be a source of inspiration. There are many solved problems, and many unsolved too. The old version can be found on *archives ouvertes*, too: https://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-01813978/document